# error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `questgiver.iscompleted_questgiver'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access a script named `questgiver` from a `GameObject` tagged as `Jenny_NPC`. However whenever I access a non-static boolean variable named `iscompleted_questgiver`, I'm having an error. I've browsed and searched the same error others are getting but I cant seem to find the exact same scenario I'm experiencing right now.

```
void Show_Quest_Update()
{
    GameObject Jennny_Quest = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Jenny_NPC"); 
    Jennny_Quest.GetComponent<questgiver>();

    Quest_List ();

    if(questgiver.iscompleted_questgiver == false)
    {
        title_index = 0;
        infos_index = 0;
        npc_index = 0;
    }

    quest_title = quest [title_index, infos_index];
    quest_objectives = quest [title_index, infos_index + 3];
    quest_rewards = quest [title_index, infos_index + 4];
    quest_target = npc [npc_index];

    Panel ();
}
```

Comment: Maybe the `GetComponent<questgiver>` method returns a reference to an object, which you need to assign to a variable... just a thought.

Comment: You need to create an instance of `questgiver` to reach it's `iscompleted_questgiver` member since it is not `static`. Like; `var instance = new questgiver();` and `instance.iscompleted_questgiver` etc..

Comment: Please spoon feed me. Im dying.

Comment: In your code, questgiver is uses as the type (the class name of the script).
You should do something like this : 
     questgiver qg = Jennny_Quest.GetComponent<questgiver>();

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the `questgiver` class to access it in your current script.

```
void Show_Quest_Update()
{
    GameObject Jennny_Quest = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Jenny_NPC"); 
    questgiver myQuestGiver = Jennny_Quest.GetComponent<questgiver>();

    Quest_List ();

    if(myQuestGiver.iscompleted_questgiver == false)
    {
        title_index = 0;
        infos_index = 0;
        npc_index = 0;
    }

    quest_title = quest [title_index, infos_index];
    quest_objectives = quest [title_index, infos_index + 3];
    quest_rewards = quest [title_index, infos_index + 4];
    quest_target = npc [npc_index];

    Panel ();
}
```

Comment: OMFG! Thank you so much James Hogle! Salvation came from you. I love you!

Answer (score 0):

From the line

```
Jennny_Quest.GetComponent<questgiver>();
```

I deduce that `questgiver` is a class, not an object.

So, when you do this:

```
if(questgiver.iscompleted_questgiver == false)
```

you want to access the **class member** `iscompleted_questgiver` which must be `static`.

The bug resides in the definition of `questgiver` not having marked `iscompleted_questgiver` with `static`.

Making it `static` will completely change the nature of this **object member** to **class member**, and may not be what you expect or need.

Review accurately what you are doing, because there seems to be a semantic (understanding) problem.